# How to calculate by referring to other columns written textually in a column in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

Column A has a Formula String like '100-[B]'.

Is there a way to calculate the actual value of column [B]?

The value of column A can actually be Formulas for calculation like '100-[C]' or '50-[B]'.

Comment: I don't understand what you are seeing. 
If you want to calculate [B] from [A], then I presume you see [A] as a value, not as a formula. In that case, what stops you from creating a calculated column [B] as 100-[A]?
Otherwise, where is this expression stored? Can you clarify with an example?